# How can I run command in virtual machine from a local user?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-api-management

I want to run a command in azure virtual machine as a local user and not as a system user.
I am using ARM template and executing a command in it. but I don't see any way run command as a local user.
Is there any azure cli or rest API call from which I can define from which user the following command should execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#restrictions) when you're using Run Command:

[image: Scripts run as System on Windows.]

So, it's not possible to run commands in VM from a local user.

You may consider using other possibilities to [run scripts in your Windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-scripts-in-vm) like
**Hybrid Runbook Worker** or **Serial console**. You also could configure WinRM to execute PowerShell Script on a remote windows Azure machine, refer to [this1](http://www.ntweekly.com/2020/09/19/how-to-enable-winrm-on-windows-machines/) and [this2](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1289/configure-winrm-execute-powershell-remote-azure-with-arm) and [this3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/winrm).